# QnA Maker giving incorrect results to similar questions

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

I have built a chatbot that answers questions related to Sustainable Development Goals (SDGs) using QnA Maker service. As a part of that, the main functionality of the bot is to answer different SDGs like what is SDG 1, what is SDG 2.... what is SDG 17.

How can I get accurate predictions from QnA Maker in this scenario where the questions are so similar as currently, the QnA Maker is always returning the answer for what is SDG 1 when I ask questions like what is SDG 16, 15, 14, etc even though the knowledge base has exact same questions

Comment: Have you tried adding additional phrasings to see if that improves detection? For example, you might try adding "SDG 1" as a phrasing in addition to the whole utterance. Not sure if that will help but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, @billoverton for your suggestion. I tried it already. It didn't work. It's just not only that question, but there are also many other similar questions like what is the agenda of sdg 11, what is the mandate of sdg 11 etc. for each sdg which are currently predicted as sdg 1 by QnA Maker

Comment: In that case you have to LUIS to distinguish user intent to make difference each entities.

Comment: I could use LUIS @MdFaridUddinKiron but I thought QnA Maker is more feasible for this requirement as each question is mapped to a particular answer.

Comment: @PraneethNooli I have tried and that's works for me. You could have a look the way I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by using the parameter "Top" from [QnAMakerOptions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.qna.qnamakeroptions?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) when calling the [GetAnswersAsync method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.ai.qna.qnamaker.getanswersasync?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable&viewFallbackFrom=botbuilder-dotnet-stable%20QnAMaker.GetAnswersAsync%20Method%20(Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA)Generates%20an%20answer%20from%20the%20knowledge%20base.%20learn.microsoft.com#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_AI_QnA_QnAMaker_GetAnswersAsync_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_ITurnContext_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_AI_QnA_QnAMakerOptions_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_String__System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Double__). I kept the value of the parameter "Top" to be 20.

If there are very similar questions in a Knowledgebase, Azure Search does not return relevant QnA pairs in the default list of results. These results are re-ranked by the final QnA Maker ranker if the parameter "top" is used.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not surprised. Looking at the just the characters of those questions, if your QnA KB is trained to recognize 'What is SDG 1' and does, to a high lvl of certainity, then 'What is SDG 1x' is going to be recognized simply based on the percentage of matching characters. To QnA maker:

'What is SDG 1x' **ALL** look like 'What is SDG 1'. You need to go into your QnA KB, and train it so that questions like 'What is SDG 19' has a 100% certainty. You can check this by looking at the 'inspect' element of the 'test' feature:

[image: QnA Maker Identical Questions]

As you can see from my image 'One' was a possible anser to this question, but 'One' is what I have as the answer to 'What is SDG 1'. (ignore the other answer, i do alot of testing on this KB). If you go into inspect like this, and you see that the wrong answer is selected, you can simply chose the right one, then retrain your KB.

I did this, choosing the wrong answer repeated, then retraining, until I got my KB (despite having a perfect answer already), to respond with 100% certainty with the wrong answer (shown below):

[image: Forced retrain to wrong answer in KB]

You're going to have to do something similar, but with the correct answer.

> It's just not only that question, but there are also many other similar questions like what is the agenda of sdg 11, what is the mandate of sdg 11 etc. for each sdg which are currently predicted as sdg 1 by QnA Maker

The idea that one question -> one answer is a good one, but you're going to have to work a bit more if all the questions look the same. Additionally, if you think this is going to come up when working with customers, you can code into your bot to return the top 3 or 5 answers, and have your bot do a follow up question like "I'm not sure I understood, did you mean '1' or '17' or '19'?", then have the user select which one they meant.

Comment: Thank you for trying this out. I think in the cases where there are very few questions, QnA Maker is not having any issue but my current knowledge base has around 550 question & answer pairs. When I test what is SDG 16, I'm getting the answer for SDG 1 and I'm not even able to see the correct answer for SDG 16 in the inspect option. Even If I try to provide the new answer for that question, it is creating a brand new question and it is of no use.

Comment: Are they ALL extremely similar questions like that? "What is 123" and "what is 124" and "what is 125?" Because you might need a more refined solution if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, they all are similar questions (SDG 1, SDG 2,....SDG 17)